# Error in sub report of crystal report in Formula Field

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm making a sub report in Crystal Report using coding.One error come in Formula field that I can not understand because of all the things are perfect.

Formula Field:

```
if {Command.opbal}<0 then "Dr." Else "Cr."
```

> error like : This field name is not known. Error in File
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Debtors_Total_Outstanding_Report
>   {A682B99D-A38B-43F3-BB05-63C258E9E0E2}.rpt: Error in formula . 'if
>   {Command.opbal}<0 then 0 else {Command.opbal}' This field name is not
>   known.

when click on Report.

i use command button like:

```
select *  from {?database}.dbo.AC_LEDGER

string str = "select crbal*-1 as crbal, glname, glcode,contprsn, refby, glphone1, glcity, glphone2, email, crlimit, restorddueamt  from glmast WHERE drgroup='A3402' and crbal<>0 and glcode in(" + strSelection + ")";
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con2);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ad.Fill(ds);

path = Server.MapPath("Debtors_Total_Outstanding_Report.Rpt");
cr = new ReportDocument();
cr.Load(path);

cr.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

cr.SetParameterValue(0,ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString());
cr.SetParameterValue(1,company_name);
cr.SetParameterValue(2, database_name);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Comment: what is ""Dr." Else "Cr.""? explain more

Comment: i set when opbal <0 it is Debit display otherwise Credit display.

Comment: r u using if {Command.opbal}<0 then 0 else {Command.opbal} in other formula...?

Comment: yes sir. i use this same formula with another formula field name.

Comment: "opbal" is a field and of which type?

Comment: there are three parameter in my Main Report.

Comment: remove(for test) this line and run it,see the result: cr.SetParameterValue(0,ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString());
            cr.SetParameterValue(1,company_name);
            cr.SetParameterValue(2, database_name);//what is the result?

Comment: and another qusetion what's your Formula Field in cr?

Comment: i am not using or set formula field by coding .

Comment: when i remove these three parameter it and run it ask me to give one by one textbox to enter these value. that i can not want.... these three value i want to pass by this coding...

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo? Your select query is returning crbal and your formula field refers to opbal?